# Jquery fileupload - including the plugin inside a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm using Jquery fileupload from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. When I include the plugin form inside a form, error comes out.
This is the error:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://www.mydomain.com/jQuery-File-Upload_9.5.3/jQuery-File-Upload-9.5.3/%5Bobject%20Object%5D"

This is what I did in my index.php page

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="post">

<!-- the plugin -->
<form id="fileupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
..........
</form>
<!-- end of plugin -->

</form>
```

However, it works fine if it is not inside a form. Anyone know how to make it works inside a form?

I have look for the similar question here [Ajax call with jquery-fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605008/ajax-call-with-jquery-fileupload) , but didn't get the answer from it. Anyone could help?

Comment: how about sharing a fiddle of the same!

Comment: You simply cannot have a nested `<form>`, it won't work, I had a similar situation too and had to adjust the design to keep the form out.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, can you share on how you adjust the design to keep the form out?

Comment: @user2991183 It's not a solution, it's design specific. I made it look like file attaching is a separate section and put in the fileupload `<form>` there. Or else one thing you can do is, do not put the nested form tags, instead while AJAX submission, enclose the file inputs within the `<form>` tags and send them. This will depend on how you are submitting the files though.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, thanks for your suggestions, the solution is actually quite simple...the fileupload plugin doesn't need a form tag....I replace the <form id="fileupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> </form> with <div id="fileupload"></div>. Everything work fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the perfect answer, but it worked for me.

Well I had similar issue and I developed the file-upload plugin in a separate form and it worked (however i never tried nested forms).

Because of that I had to tweak css and JS to look all seamless to user. But at the end it all worked.

So try doing that and it might work.